# Issue reloading applet using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I developed an applet and I reload it when it finishes some task. I accomplished that using javascript:

```
function startApplet() {
  // code to setup "object" tag
  var appletHtml = '<object name= ....'
  document.getElementById("applet_tag").innerHTML = appletHtml;
}

function restartApplet() {
  if (document.getElementById("applettag")) {
    document.getElementById("applet_tag").innerHTML = '';
  }
  startApplet();
}
```

That works perfectly in some machines but in others the javascript code is executed but the applet doesn't reload (disappear current instance, start a new one)

I already tried with `<param name="cache_option" value="no">` or using jquery code to reset applet div with no success.

Anyone knows about this issue or knows another way to reload the applet without refreshing page?

---

*Edit: More info about issue:*

Looking at Java console, I infer that applet efectively restart, but I think I need that the applet **restart in a new JVM instance**. Below, I attached an extract of the java console:

```
basic: Applet loaded.
...
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
...
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@d062ed
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@ca5165

basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@185c219
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://...
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 359544 us, pluginInit dt 55298741 us, TotalTime: 55658285 us
Applet inicializado
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using separate\_jvm to start applet in individual JVMs not always working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461807/using-separate-jvm-to-start-applet-in-individual-jvms-not-always-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [applet in new jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461807/using-separate-jvm-to-start-applet-in-individual-jvms-not-always-working), using **separate_jvm** applet parameter, official deployment documentation in [applet deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SEPARATE_JVM). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly calling startApplet put it on a 15 second timeout. That will allow the jvm to exit.

```
function restartApplet() {
    if (document.getElementById("applettag")) {
        document.getElementById("applet_tag").innerHTML = '';
    }
    setTimeout("startApplet()", 15000);
```

### }

New JVM
Not tried this but you could

```
var apltIdCnt = 1
function startApplet() {
    // code to setup "object" tag
    var appletHtml = '<div id=aplInner'  + apltIdCnt + ' <object name= ....'
    document.getElementById("applet_tag").innerHTML = appletHtml;
    apltIdCnt += 1 ;//or apltIdCnt++
}
```

this might help if other tags have a different jvm

Comment: Thank you tgkprog, but the issue is still present. In my post I added some extra info.

Comment: not sure about a new jvm. can you put a new simple applet on same page and run in same browser and see if it has 2 jvms? then maybe you need to make a new div tag (with a new id); see edit in answer

Comment: I tried with different tag id with no change in result. Thank you anyway.

Comment: i see you found a solution and it was part of the API - great!